# Trying not to store the same values in an arraylist

Tags: java, oop

I have a textfile formated like this:

```
David
David
David
Vo
Vo
```

and here are the classes `Ord` and `Ordliste` (which means "word", and "word list") which are two separated files.

Word: (`Verdi` means "value", `hentAntall` means "get value", and `oekAntall` means "raise value")

```
class Ord {

  private String tekst;
  private int verdi = hentAntall();

  public Ord(String tekst) {
    this.tekst = tekst;
    this.verdi = verdi;
  } 

  public String toString(){
    return tekst;
  }

  public int hentAntall() {
    return verdi;
  }

  public void oekAntall() {
    verdi++;
  }
}
```

Word list:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

class Ordliste {

  private ArrayList<Ord> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public void readFile(String filnavn) throws Exception {

    File fil = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(fil);
    Ord empty = new Ord("");
    list.add(empty);

    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
      String linjeTekst = s.nextLine();
      addOrd(linjeTekst);
    }

    System.out.println(list.get(1));
    System.out.println(list.get(1).hentAntall());
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
   //I use this part to check the arraylist
  }

  private void addOrd(String ord) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
      if (list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ord)) {
        list.get(i).oekAntall();
      }
      else {
        Ord nyOrd = new Ord(ord);
        list.add(nyOrd);
      }
    }
  }
```

I think that there is something wrong with my addWord method, as the values stored in my arraylist is `David David David Vo Vo`, and not just `David Vo` which I believe. I'm also not supposed to add anything to my `Ord` class.

Comment: An ```ArrayList``` stores duplicates. You want to use some variation of a ```Set``` which does omits duplicates.

Comment: Why just don't use Set collection?

Comment: But if you take a look at my addWord method, it is only supposed to raise the value by 1 if it is the same word, and add a new word to the list if it is a new word. @Siddhartha.

Comment: Yes, but if you see the for, you only verify the first value on the array list. and if it is not the same, you insert the new value... you are not looking on all the array list. The insert must be outside the for statement.

Comment: And I don't understand why you are using this "list.get(i).oekAntall();"

Comment: @bugs2919 he doesn't verify only the first value. It verifies them all. But each time a different value is found, the word is added to the list.

Comment: see my answer... i edit it, because you are using this: list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ord)  list.get(i) -> you get the object you need to access the value it must be like this: list.get(i).tekst.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ord)

Comment: @JB Nizet the problem is the equalsIgnoreCase, he is comparing with an object, not the property tekst of the readed object.

Comment: @bugs2919 no. He's comparing with the toString() of the object, which returns the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
private void addOrd(String ord){
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
      //You need to comapre te tekst field not the object
      if (list.get(i).tekst.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ord)) {
         found = true;
         break;
      }
   }
if(!found){
    Ord nyOrd = new Ord(ord);
    list.add(nyOrd);
 }
```

}

Comment: You need to search on all the arraylist, and after that if you don't found an equal value, you proced to insert into the arraylist. In your code, you only verified the first value on the list......

Comment: I really wonder why you added the explanation in a comment and not into the answer itself?

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code step by step, and you should understand. The debugger is your friend. Use it.

You start by adding an empty word in the list.

Then you read the first word: David. You loop on every element of the list:

- is David equal to ""? No, so you add David to the list
- is David equal to David? Yes, so you increment David's count.

Then you read the second word: David. You loop on every element of the list:

- is David equal to ""? No, so you add David to the list
- is David equal to David? Yes, so you increment David's count.
- is David equal to David? Yes, so you increment David's count.

etc. etc.

You should instead test if the list contains David. If it doesn't, then add it. Otherwise, increment its count.

The easiest (and much faster) way to do that would be to use a `Map<String, Ord>` instead of a list.

Comment: thanks, i could also do this. but i was supposed to use arraylist